# Right side border of textInputLayout is cropped in alertdialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

Here is the custom layout `password_alert.xml`

I have tried increasing the padding in `ConstraintLayout`. But it still did not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_password"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/enter_password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_enter_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is the code for alert dialog

```
val enterPassDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        enterPassDialog.setTitle("Password Protected")
        val pass = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.enter_password_dialog,null)
        val etPassword = pass.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_enter_password)
        enterPassDialog.setView(pass)

        enterPassDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL") { dialog, _ ->
            dialog.cancel()
            finish()
        }

        enterPassDialog.setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->

        }

        enterPassDialog.setOnCancelListener { dialog ->

        }

        val enterDialog = enterPassDialog.create()
        enterDialog.show()
```

I am using Android API 22 as a test device. 
Here is the output image -

[image: alert dialog image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` with the same layout:

```
    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle("Dialog") 
            .setView(R.layout.password_alert) 
            .setPositiveButton("Ok",  /* listener = */null)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",  /* listener = */null)
            .show()
```

[image]

Just a tip: use `app:endIconMode="password_toggle"` instead of `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"`(deprecated)

Comment: It's still showing cropped border even after using Material Dialog.

Comment: @Rajeshkumar only on API 22 or also in other version (try with the emulator)?